# After insertion of new element resize not triggered automatically in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am writing a plugin for nexus oss which internally use extjs framework .

The original nexus website is [here](http://repository.sonatype.org/) .

I want to insert an I frame above the sonatype header panel . so I wrote jquery command to insert the iframe in the beginning of div with id "ext-comp-1006" .

But after insert the screen became like [what I got](http://s16.postimg.org/3s39bptl1/fig1.png).

But I want it to be something like [this](http://s21.postimg.org/3n5sgptx3/fig3.png)

The problem was may be the screen did not get resized after the iframe insertion .What should I do to get the required screen .Why did the resize not happen by itself.Is there any resize function I need to call manually .
Please help .

Comment: what is the reason for negative vote ?

Comment: yes, did you apply doLayout() for inserting component....

Comment: No.ok, I understood the mistake. Thanks .

Comment: I did Ext.getCmp('ext-comp-1006').doComponentLayout() seeing the doc for ext js but nothing seems to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did

```
Ext.EventManager.fireResize();
```

after loading the iframe and this solves the problem.

Comment: Great that u solved the problem. You had made entire resize 
!!

Comment: I still did not figure out why doLayout() did not work. Sorry if my answers are vague. I am damn new to this framework.

Comment: if you add any component to any container, extjs will automatically do doLayout()... If you are using other framework along with extjs then u manually need to call doLayout() methods of the container. I don't understand why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: By components did u mean the in the context of extjs ? . I just inserted an element with jquery inside div tag with id ext-comp-1006 . Is it not a legitimate process as per the framework ?

Comment: @Hariharan you can try by adding  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="1213px"> tag as top most element in div with id ext-comp-1011  in page http://repository.sonatype.org

Comment: Mu suggestion : I hope that id "ext-comp-1006" is dynamic generated one, we can't relay on it. so don't use as Ext.getCmp('ext-comp-1006').

Comment: You can witness the case similar to mine . now do Ext.getCmp("ext-comp-1011").doLayout() . and you will find that nothing happens .

Comment: No id remains constant for a system. I witnessed that it is the same even after restarting nexus any number of times.

Comment: ("ext-comp-1011") are autogenertaed id by extjs framework. it will keep on changing everytime u render.

Comment: if you have doubt just do this in developer console after seeing the id after the page has loaded

Comment: ok but any time I refresh http://repository.sonatype.org I get the same id ext-comp-1011.

Comment: can we move to chat ?

Comment: try one thing, provide an static id and try it out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37296/discussion-between-harish-kayarohanam-and-hariharan)

Answer (score 0):

Apply doLayout() after inserting the component to parent container...

Comment: In that I am unable to do doLayout . Can you please tell to which element I have to do do layout in the https://repository.sonatype.org website . I am pretty new to extjs .

Comment: I did Ext.getCmp('ext-comp-1006').doComponentLayout() seeing the doc for ext js but nothing seems to happen

Comment: Ext.getCmp('ext-comp-1006').doLayout() also does nothing